# Позиционирование. Текст на фото

Tags: css

Есть фото и текст. Фото превью, поэтому размер всегда одинаковый. Как текст поместить вниз изображения и как затемнить изображение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эффект, который я пытаюсь получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Text можно и с помощью flex разместить снизу. 
по hover просто затемнять через opacity например.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/NINTCHDBPICT000414976532.jpg)  ;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;


}

.box span {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* затемнение по наведнии  */
.box { opacity:1; }
.box:hover { opacity:.7; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>  Что надо знать о деле Ивана Голунова</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Выше уже был дан ответ по поводу текста. Его можно разместить с помощью флексов.
Но вот ещё вариант, касаемо затемнения.
Идея в том, чтобы навешивать прозрачность дополнительному элементу, который будет отвечать за непосредственно затемнение. Картинку можно вставить фоном.

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
}

.opacity {
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.img:hover .opacity {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="img">
    <div class="opacity">
      <span class="text">Privet</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```